# After .htaccess rewrite to redirect root URL to subdirectory, files get not loaded properly

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

What I did was this .htaccess rule:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?example\.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /static/somefolder/$1 [L]
```

In the folder is a static html and some css. The html now tries to load the css from root, which is clearly not want I want.

Actually I wanted all requests to be redirected, except for one folder.
So I then used:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?example\.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/downloads/.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /static/somefolder/$1    [L]
```

But this throws an 'Internal Server Error'.

What did I miss here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to exclude the destination you are rewriting to :

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?example\.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/downloads/.*
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/static/

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /static/somefolder/$1     [L]
```

Otherwise you will get an infinite loop error because /static/somefolder/* also matches the pattern ^(.*)$